# Couldn't access persisted data in a workbook after submitting excel add-in

Tags: excel, office-js, excel-addins

We are trying to create a demo version workbook which will have predefined data persisted in it. But this functionality is not available for public users we have a dev mode manifest with similar id to that of the submitted manifest. If we persist data using this dev mode manifest we couldn't access it from the Add-in available in App Source. Could anyone let me know why we couldn't access this data and is there a possibility to resolve this ?

Comment: which API that you are using to persist the data in dev mode?

Comment: We are using this Office.context.document.settings.set() inbuilt function

Comment: Office.context.document.settings.set() is used to save custom settings of the content or task pane add-in. It goes with Addin instead of workbook. Given you are using different addin, then that's expected behavior. Maybe you can try other way like Excel.CustomProperty to see if it can meet your requriement. Related doc can found: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.customproperty?view=excel-js-preview

Comment: @MandytMSFT please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.settings?view=excel-js-preview the documentation says the this API saves the content to the document

Comment: @naveen ashok, yes, the setting is saved in document but in different part. It saved in webextension.xml binding with addin. You can easily confirm by change the .xlsx extension to .zip extension and unzip the file. setting is saved in one of the webextension.xml file.

Comment: @MandytMSFT we do not share the file by zipping it we share only copies of the .xlsx file. Should we still use customProperty ? if so let me know why.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go two ways:

1. Excel way: Create and use one sheet (can be hidden for user) as a data table for app, in this case when you are starting your app you just need to check the sheet existence by its unique name. This case acceptable for any workbook movements and user will not lose its persistent data.
2. Web way: as Addin itself is a WebView you can use LocalStorage as same as IndexedDB, which brings all power of local database for your app. In this case the data will be tied with exact PC and user **will** lose their data if you. But again, as it is web technology you can synchronize it with any remote Database to keep track of any changes.